# Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes

Tags: java, mockito

In my code I have a method which use ObjectMapper.readValue and I would like to mock this for testing purpose.
Here is the partition of code :

```
     if (entity != null) {
                    String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
                    objectMapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_SOURCE, true);
                    return objectMapper.readValue(result, classeObjetRetour);
                }
```

And when I am trying to de this in my test class :

```
    String retour = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
    IdentifiantEnveloppe identifiantAttendu = new IdentifiantEnveloppe();
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = mock(ObjectMapper.class);
    doReturn(identifiantAttendu).when(objectMapper).readValue(retour, IdentifiantEnveloppe.class);
```

I hava the following error :

```
    org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Mockito cannot mock this class: class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.

Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes.
If you're not sure why you're getting this error, please report to the mailing list.
```

If someone could help me I would be grateful. I am in Java 8.

Comment: `ObjectMapper` is not supposed to be final or private. Which version of Jackson databind you're using?

Comment: Hello I use 2.10.2 for jackson DataBind

Comment: I am not convinced you should be mocking the ObjectMapper, it doesnt appear to be an injected helper.  The ObjectMapper is doing some work on your behalf.  Personally I would write my test such that ObjectMapper receives valid and invalid input and test your Class/method behaves as it should for the given inputs.

Answer (score 3):

```
 if (entity != null) {
                String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(); // this line is the problem.
                objectMapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_SOURCE, true);
                return objectMapper.readValue(result, classeObjetRetour);
            }
```

Since you create a new instance of ObjectMapper above your mocking doesn't work. As in the last line in your test class will never happen:

```
 String retour = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
IdentifiantEnveloppe identifiantAttendu = new IdentifiantEnveloppe();
ObjectMapper objectMapper = mock(ObjectMapper.class);
doReturn(identifiantAttendu).when(objectMapper).readValue(retour, IdentifiantEnveloppe.class);
```

Because the objectMapper where you call the Mockito.when() on, is another instance than the one inside the class. So objectMapper.readValue() is never called on your mock.

You should try to mock the objectMapper inside your class. You can define the objectMapper as a class field so you can inject the objectMapper in your class through the constructor. In your test class you can then inject a mock(ObjectMapper.class) instead of a real one.

Comment: I tried to add this in my code : 
`private static final ObjectMapper OBJECTMAPPER = new ObjectMapper();`
And I have this error : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonMerge.